# How would I go about writing a test for an extension function for my TextView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, testing

```
fun TextView.makeSectionOfTextBold(vararg textsToBold: String) {
     val spannableString = SpannableString(this.text)
     for (textToBold in textsToBold) {
         val startIndex = this.text.indexOf(textToBold)
         val endIndex = startIndex + textToBold.length
 
         if (startIndex >= 0) {
             spannableString.setSpan(
                 StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
                 startIndex,
                 endIndex,
                 Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
             )
         }
     }
     this.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
 }
```

This is my code. I was hoping to write a test for this but I am not sure how I would go about doing that.
Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to figure out a way to write tests for this. I'm posting a sample test here for anyone who might need it in the future.
This is in Kotlin and also you would have to mock the context which isn't relevant so not showing here.

```
fun testFun(){
     val mockTextView = TextView(mockApplicationContext)
     val text = "Sample Text"
     val textToBold = "Sample"
     mockTextView.text = text 
     mockTextView.makeSectionOfTextBold(textToBold )
     val spanableString = SpannableString(text)
     val boldSpan = spanableString.getSpan(0, textToBold.length, StyleSpan::class.java)
     assertThat(boldSpan[0].style).isEqualTo(Typeface.BOLD)
}
```